# MariaDB crashing once per day with memory issues -- allocating more memory does not fix

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

Every day for the past week, our MariaDB is crashing (typically late at night). It crashes with this in the logs:

```
2018-10-20  6:44:35 140525276776704 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer 
pool, size = 184.0M
InnoDB: mmap(202080256 bytes) failed; errno 12
2018-10-20  6:44:35 140525276776704 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate 
memory for the buffer pool
2018-10-20  6:44:35 140525276776704 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2018-10-20  6:44:35 140525276776704 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-10-20  6:44:35 140525276776704 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2018-10-20  6:44:35 140525276776704 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2018-10-20  6:44:35 140525276776704 [ERROR] Aborting
```

or sometimes this:

```
2018-10-17  9:05:54 140453757659392 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 128663552 bytes)
```

Within 30 or so minutes of restarting (where it works for about 24 hours), I always see this in the logs:

```
2018-10-20  8:03:55 139957660669696 [Warning] InnoDB: Difficult to find free blocks in the buffer pool (21 search iterations)! 0 failed attempts to flush a page!
2018-10-20  8:03:55 139957660669696 [Note] InnoDB: Consider increasing the buffer pool size.
```

We've increased this innodb_buffer_pool_size several times in my.cnf.d/server.cnf several times but it doesn't fix the issue. Here's the [mysqld] section from that:

```
[mysqld]
basedir = /usr
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
expire_logs_days = 10
key_buffer_size = 16M
log-error = /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
max_allowed_packet = 16M
max_binlog_size = 100M
max_connections = 151
pid-file = /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid
port = 3306
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size = 16M
skip-external-locking
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
ssl = false
ssl-ca = /etc/mysql/cacert.pem
ssl-cert = /etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
ssl-key = /etc/mysql/server-key.pem
thread_cache_size = 8
thread_stack = 256K
tmpdir = /tmp
user = mysql
innodb_buffer_pool_size=184M
innodb_log_buffer_size=128M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=1
```

I'm no DBA and we're a small operation, and I'd really appreciate the help!

mysqltuner.pl output:

```
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.1.31-MariaDB
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

Performance Metrics
[--] Up for: 4h 35m 15s (369K q [22.368 qps], 87 conn, TX: 2G, RX: 226M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 67% / 33%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 9.6G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 930.1M
[--] Other process memory: 4.5G
[--] Total buffers: 496.0M global + 2.9M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 0B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 703.0M (7.16% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 930.1M (9.47% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/369K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 47% (72/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (0/87)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 22.4% (45K cached / 201K selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 8 sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 2742
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (0 on disk / 2K total)
[!!] Thread cache hit rate: 17% (72 created / 87 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 91% (62 open / 68 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (25/16K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (216K immediate / 216K locks)

InnoDB Metrics
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 184.0M/95.4M
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (52.1739130434783 %): 48.0M * 2/184.0M should be equal 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[--] InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size not used or defined in your version
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.96% (196286081 hits/ 196367903 total)
[OK] InnoDB Write log efficiency: 98.79% (5736869 hits/ 5806871 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 70002 writes)

General recommendations:
    Control warning line(s) into /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log file
    Control error line(s) into /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log file
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    Performance schema should be activated for better diagnostics
    Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys
    Before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group read this: 
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    thread_cache_size (> 8)
    performance_schema = ON enable PFS
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=23M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for everyone who looked. I was hoping to find an answer relating to MDB config or something, but Occam's Razor: the error was a rogue process related to an unknown upgrade by another team member. It was just eating all the memory up.

If you have this problem, or these error messages: consider that there's nothing wrong with your MDB and might just be a localized server/vm problem instead.

Comment: Are you still crashing once per day?  If not, please let us know and what you found to resolve the crashing frequency.

Comment: What is result of  SELECT @@innodb_log_file_size?  The message from the error log indicates 202mb ram was not available when requested. What are the other apps running on this server?   Please at least post results of TOP  and 
 SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  and  SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; for clues to be analyzed.

Answer (score 0):

128663552  bytes is ~ roughly 128 megabytes. The issue isn't the increasing of the buffer pool, it's the fact that your server doesn't have the memory in order to run the processes. Check to see what else on the server is using up memory, and consider adding more ram, or LOWERING the pool size to limits within your server.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've allocated more memory and it's still crashing. It seems like MariaDB crashes several times, and as it starts crashing, the memory fills up within 30-60 minutes.

Comment: @jstrange88 For help, please post requested information.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion to consider for my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
thread_cache_size=100  # from 8 for CAP suggested in v8.0 refman to avoid OOM
query_cache_min_res_unit=512  # from 4096 to conserve RAM used in QC
```

and this will reduce threads_created count.

Please repost COMPLETE Mysqltuner.pl report after 24 hours or more of UPTIME.

Comment: @jstrange88 Wondering if you have implemented the 2 suggestons of Nov 5, 2018?  2 more suggestions I would recommend are  query_cache_type=0 and query_cache_size=0 to disable Query Cache to conserve RAM and CPU cycles managing the QC. The MySQLTuner.pl report you have posted represents 4h 35m of activity.  Please post more recent for your entire workday, if possible.  Happy Thanksgiving.